# Convergence of a sequence involving integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

> Consider $f:[-\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic (infinite differentiable) and periodic. Define
>   $a_n:= \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{-inx}dx$ (the Fourier coefficient of $f$). Show that the sequence $\{n a_n\} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Here is my thinking:
$$\begin{array}{l}
|n{a_n} - 0| = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\left| {\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {nf} (x){e^{ - inx}}dx} \right| \le \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\left| {nf(x){e^{ - inx}}} \right|} dx\\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{}&{}&{}&{}
\end{array} \le \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\left\| f \right\|\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\left| {n{e^{ - inx}}} \right|} dx
\end{array}$$ Then I stuck to infer it further (since I can't say the integral above will converges eventually.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the triangle inequality to bring the absolute value inside the integral — it will not help, as $\lvert e^{-inx}\rvert =1$. Instead, use integration by parts.
$$
\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  nf (x)e^{- inx} dx = \left[i f(x)e^{- inx}\right]^\pi_{-\pi} -i \int_{[-\pi,\pi]} f^\prime(x) e^{- inx}dx
$$
For the first term, leverage the periodicity of $f$. For the second, use for instance the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).